# JQuery setInterval is not working after multiple hover sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to emulate the footer of a powerpoint presentation. So this is the code

```js
$(function() {
        $('.presentation').on({
          mouseleave: function() {      
   setInterval(function () {
   if(!$("input").is(":focus") && !$(".presentation:hover").length > 0 && !$('.bp-controls').hasClass('show')){    
         $('.bp-controls').fadeOut(); 
               $('.bp-controls').removeClass('show');       
           }
       }, 4000);
          },
          mouseenter: function() {
   $('.bp-controls').fadeTo(500, 1, function() {
           // Animation complete.
        $('.bp-controls').addClass('show');
             });             
           }
        });
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="presentation">
         <img src="Main.png" width="50%">
         <div class="bp-controls"><input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*"></div>
        </div>
```

I don't understand why setInterval works the first and maybe the second time when the document is ready but then it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: You will probably need to clear the interval when you mousenter otherwise every time you leave you create a new interval.  Also should you be using an interval - doesn't seem that you should run that every 4 seconds

Comment: I think Pete nailed it. Interval doesn't seem to make much sense unless it should be looping. Also, every time you mouse over, a new interval is added to the DOM. I would think you'd want to use setTimeout() rather than setInterval() as setTimeout() will only run once after a predetermined amount of time (the second parameter in setTimeout).

Comment: Thank you very much! i use setTimeout now and now is working better, the only thing wrong is that now if I want to enter multiple time in the presentation's div (so enter, leave, enter, leave within the 4 seconds) the interval is not clear so bp-controls div fade out. Instead i want that the interval of setTimeout go to clear every time that i go inside of the presentation div. What can I do? thank you guys @Pete

Comment: Than cancel the timeout...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding multiple intervals. You need to clear then when you leave. Should be a timeout also, I doubt you want to keep firing it.

```
$('.presentation').on({
  mouseleave: function() {       
    this.timer = setTimeout(function () {}, 4000);
  },
  mouseenter: function() {
    if (this.timer) window.clearTimeout(this.timer)
  }
});
```